# Bluetooth socket communication

Tags: sockets, bluetooth, communication

I have a problem with StreamSocket's by Bluetooth connection.

I have a phone Nokia Lumia 920 and some bluetooth headset. This headset have proprietary service. I know uuid of this service.

I implemented code for communication with this service.

> PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:Paired"] = "";
>   var peers = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();
>   StreamSocket socket = new StreamSocket();
>   var uuid = "there is uuid";
>   await socket.ConnectAsync(peers[0].HostName, uuid, SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket);

This code work success.

Then I send bytes message to headset by IOutputStream.

> DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
>   byte[] a = {0x01, 0x01 , 0x10, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01};
>   dataWriter.WriteBytes(a);
>   await dataWriter.StoreAsync();

This code work success.

Then I have to get bytes message.

> DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
>   dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
>   await dataReader.LoadAsync(10);
>   while (dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
>   {
>       byte bb = dataReader.ReadByte();
>   }

This code don't work success.

In the line

> await dataReader.LoadAsync(10);
>   app hangs here. But the response must  necessarily be.

Why is this  a problem?

Do sockets support communication through Bluetooth by uuid in windows phone 8?

Can you help me?

Thank you all.